# Las fuentes de fontawesome.com no se ven en mi página web

Tags: html, css, fuentes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../iconos/fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.css">
```

Agrego los iconos en el html con sus respectivas clases, y no aparecen en el documento. La dirección del link está correcta, allí es donde tengo los archivos y carpetas que instalé de Font Awesome.

```
<i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
```

Comment: Hola, podrías mostrar donde estas llamando al cdn de fontawesome?

Comment: Lo más probable es que el archivo al que haces referencia no exista. ¿Ya lo comprobaste? No hay otra manera que te podamos ayudar. Si gustas, puedes poner la referencia `href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"` para que veas que sí que funciona. La cosa es, que si el archivo no lo tienes en esa ubicación, ni modo que te muestre los íconos.

Comment: Instalé el package, no estoy usando el cdn.

Comment: Están en esa ubicación, pero pues ya. Muchas gracias, sí me funcionó. ;))